# Way to create pages quickly

Tags: plugin-recommendation, pages

I have a site structure that I want to create a bunch of empty pages - each with a particular parent page and template. Is there a faster way to do this than one-by-one? A plugin perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

Direct injection in to the DB. Have a look at the [codex for `$wpdb`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb). I'd suggest putting a line of code in to a `for()` loop so that you can run it as many times as you want.

```
<?php $wpdb->insert( $table, $data, $format ); ?>
```

Comment: Good, but I'd like to see a better solution. A plugin perhaps?